# Algolia instantsearch disjunctiveFacetsRefinements not working with facetsExcludes

Tags: javascript, algolia

```
var getallskills = document.getElementById('OpenJobs').value; 
var preselectedCategories = getallskills.split(",");
var getallskills2 = document.getElementById('HiddenField1').value;
var preselectedCategories2 = getallskills2.split(",");
var geter = "Filled";
var pregeter = geter.split(",");
var search = instantsearch({
appId: 'XXXXXXXXX',
apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
indexName: 'Jobs',
searchParameters: {
    "disjunctiveFacetsRefinements": {

        "JobTitle": preselectedCategories
},
    "facetsExcludes": {

        "Emails.User": preselectedCategories2,
        "Status": pregeter

    }
}});
```

I am trying to get disjunctiveFacetsRefinements working with facetsExcludes and it doesn't seem to work. Is there something I am doing wrong? Perhaps a bug?

Comment: Please define "not working".

Comment: Results display, however they are not the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out..... I think the problem is the disjunctiveFacetsRefinements. If you look you at my code:

```
"disjunctiveFacetsRefinements": {
//Facet Following Users
        "JobTitle": preselectedCategories//, "ToUser.EmailAddress": emailaddress
```

},

So what it does is it only looks at the "JobTitle" facet. So it limits my results. Is there a way where I can change the searchParameter to have a LIKE type query looking at searchable fields?